# Get data to NodeRed from Homepage (HighCharts)

Tags: logging, highcharts, node-red

I would like to extract the data from this chart using node-red:

http://fiskdata.se/raknare/live/live.php?locationId=109
The chart is labeled with "Preliminära resultat 2018" and I want the green and red series. I would like to have alerts and also trend the waterflow and temperature in my home automation.

In node red I am using a "http request node" -> "html node" -> "function" -> "Debug".

My Questions is:
What selector should I use in "html node"? I have tried to solve it with web developer in firefox against the webpage but I do not understand it.

And what would my function look like to convert the two series into arrays in node red? Two series with value/date.

[Image for Node_red Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6gXR.png)

Comment: could you add screenshots here, please?

Comment: Also show us what selectors you've already tried

Comment: I dont know so much about Sectors but I have tried dev, g, highcharts, highcharts.options, highcharts.series...

Comment: Picture added...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following instructions will tell you how to find the url that gets the data behind a chart on a web page:
https://onlinejournalismblog.com/2017/05/10/how-to-find-data-behind-chart-map-using-inspector/

Using those instructions, I think that for the page you have mentioned in your question it will be something like:

1. http://fiskdata.se/raknare/live/ajax/liveChart.php?counterId=232
2. http://fiskdata.se/raknare/report/ajax/ackNettoChart.php?counterId=232&exportWidth=500&exportHeight=281&disableHeader=0&english=0

So in node-red you can then create a flow consisting of an *inject* node, a *html in* node using one of the above 2 URLs and one or more nodes that parse the output of the *html in* node.

kr
Jan.